# How to revert to a earlier version for a bzr parent directory from the branch?

Tags: bazaar

I have a bzr repository "A" based on which I created a branch call "a". I revert "a" to a earlier version by "bzr uncommit", and want it affect on its parent "A" as well. I tried "bzr push :parent --no-strict" but it says "No revision to push", and "A" is still the latest version.
Hope my statement is clear and thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--no-strict` option is to make it possible to push even if there are pending changes in your working tree.

Use `--overwrite` to overwrite the parent branch with the current branch:

```
bzr push :parent --overwrite
```